# How do you implement a user journey progress bar in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, user-interface

I am new to Angular, so I've looked at the documentation and the sample code. But, what I don't understand is how can I get the progress bar to increment after the user clicks continue on each page?
There are about 15 pages in the user journey to introduce the website, so I just want a simple progress bar at the bottom to show them how far into the journey they are.
The code that I'm thinking about using is:

```
<section class="progress-section">
  <mat-progress-bar
      class = "progressbar"
      [color] = "color"
      [mode] = "mode"
      [value] = "value">
  </mat-progress-bar>
</section>
```

In the typescript file, I have:

```
color: ThemePalette = 'primary';
mode: ProgressBarMode = 'determinate';
value = 0;
```

Right now a progress bar with value 0 appears, but I want to be able to change that value in each subsequent page.

For some more background, there are about 15 pages in the user journey, and they are all coded in different components. My thought process would be to implement this progress bar in the root html/ts file and then modify the value of the progress bar somehow in each file after clicking continue? Simplest way to do it would probably be having each page have a set value, and when the page loads the progress bar goes to that value, that way I don't have to worry about backs and exits/restarts.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it really depends on what you are coding, how, and a lot of situational factor. If you page are static, the flow is simple, and each page is loaded separately. Then just go with hard coded value on each step.

Comment: I don't think the pages are static, since the website doesn't reload when I click continue. That's something I'm struggling with, since my first attempt was just having a public value that I would change at each page, but it doesn't actually update the progress bar.

Comment: do you use a different component for each page (that's what I meant by "static" ^^) ?